# Loop through string in iMacros

Tags: string, loops, imacros

Is it possible to loop through a string in iMarocs. I do not know how to do.

For Example I have a string like this:

```
SET !VAR1 "a,b,c,d,"
```

How can I loop through this string?

Windows 10
iMacros for Chrome 10.1.0 free version
Google Chrome Version 86.0.4240.111

Comment: Split the string into an array and then iterate the array ?

Comment: Yep..., exactly like @stud3nt, and exactly like I told you already in your parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum...: https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=31266#p86349